# WooCommerce order status change from payment gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, orders

I have integrated a payment gateway to accept online payments for my store running on woocommerce. Everything works fine but I noticed that woocommerce is changing the order status to `wc-processing` for all the online paid orders by default.

As per my store's functionality I want all the online paid orders to be in `wc-on-hold` status initially.

Is there any way to stop woocommerce changing the order status to `wc-processing` programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is a way, but you need to modify the payment plugin or add your own code, you can [read this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/) to understand how payments work.

Now, woocommerce use `$order->payment_complete()` method to handle the completed order, so you need to hook your own function to modify the status, [<del>here is the description of that method</del>](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_abstract_orderpayment_complete/)

Use this filter: `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status`

Comment: You are right `$order->payment_complete()` is changing the order status to `processing` in my payment plugin. I will try placing my own function instead and let you know.

Comment: Instead of `$order->payment_complete()` I added the following code and it worked as I expected. `$order->update_status('on-hold');
        add_post_meta($order->id, '_paid_date', current_time('mysql'), true);
        update_post_meta($order->id, '_transaction_id', $txnid);
        $order->reduce_order_stock();`

Answer (score 4):

Here it is a code snippet based on this [**thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders-depending-on-payment-methods/35689563#35689563). We use here **`woocommerce_thankyou`** *(that is fired just after payment has been done)* to hook our function, converting **`'processing'`** orders status to **`'on-hold'`**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_paid_order_status', 10, 1 );
function custom_woocommerce_paid_order_status( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // 'processing' orders status are converted to 'on-hold'.
    if ( is_object($order) && $order->has_status( 'processing' ) {
        $order->update_status( 'on-hold' ); 
    }

    return;
}
```

You can also target in your conditions the payment gateways for example here we bypass 3 payment gateways and target a specific payment gateway using **`"your_payment_gateway"` slug**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_paid_order_status', 10, 1 );
function custom_woocommerce_paid_order_status( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // Bypass orders with Bank wire, Cash on delivery and Cheque payment methods.
    if ( ( get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'bacs' ) || ( get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'cod' ) || ( get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'cheque' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Target your "your_payment_gateway_slug" with this conditional
    if ( is_object($order) && get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'your_payment_gateway_slug'  && $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) {
        $order->update_status( 'on-hold' ); 
    }

    return;
}
```

*This code snippets goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme.*

You can easily do anything you want, and the correct hook for paid orders is **`woocommerce_thankyou`**

References:

- [WooCommerce Class WC_Abstract_Order](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html)
- [WooCommerce: Auto complete paid Orders (depending on Payment methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders-depending-on-payment-methods/35689563#35689563)
- [Renaming WooCommerce Order Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790855/renaming-woocommerce-order-status)

Comment: Thank you so much, but in your solution the order would turn `on-hold`  where it was already been marked as `processing` from gateway. My problem is I have an email alert flow connected with order status in which `on-hold` should be first status right from the gateway processing.