# WooCommerce - Renaming and using renamed order status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

I've already renamed my order status 'completed' to 'paid' using this code

```
function wc_renaming_order_status( $order_statuses ) {
foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
    $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
    if ( 'wc-completed' === $key ) {
        $order_statuses['wc-completed'] = _x( 'Paid', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wc_renaming_order_status' );
```

My problem is that I did a page template with a list of all my orders:

```
<?php   
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$order_id = $loop->post->ID;
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
?>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $order->billing_first_name; ?> 
<?php echo $order->billing_last_name; ?></td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $order->billing_company; ?></td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $order->status; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And the **`$order->status`** still returns **`'completed'`** instead of **`'paid'`**.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal and your this specific case you could use some additional code, creating a function to display your custom renamed status:

```php
function custom_status($order){
    if($order->status == 'completed')
        return _x( 'Paid', 'woocommerce' );
    else
        return $order->status;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

In your **template page** you will use it this way:

```php
<?php   
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$order_id = $loop->post->ID;
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
?>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $order->billing_first_name; ?> 
<?php echo $order->billing_last_name; ?></td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $order->billing_company; ?></td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo custom_status($order); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**This code is tested and works.**

Reference: [Renaming WooCommerce Order Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790855/renaming-woocommerce-order-status/37795871#37795871)